# Remove a class select option is not selected

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

When i select something from a selectbox it adds a class to the

selected option this way:

```
$(
    'div#tabs input[type="text"],
    select option:selected,
    input:checked,
    textarea'
).addClass('takethis');
```

But when I select a different option it doesn't remove the class 
`takethis` from the option which I first selected. 
How can I force this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Remove class from all non-selected options:

```
$("select option:not(:selected)").removeClass("takethis");
```

Then add to selected one:

```
$("select option:selected").addClass("takethis");
```

Comment: how could i do the same for radio buttons?

Comment: Change the selector to "input:radio" instead of "select option:selected" :)

Comment: I meant: "input:radio:not(:checked)"

Comment: Acutally it's alters the option box itself. But the contents of the option box are also changed. Rather just the values should be changed. 
How can I do that?

Comment: If you mean to add/remove classes to particular options, I'm afraid it's not possible to do cross-browser safe. Styles to <SELECT> boxes apply to all children.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [removeClass](http://docs.jquery.com/Removeclass) like this:

```
$('#tabs').find('option').removeClass('takethis');
```

I am not sure what you are trying to do, though. This code:

```
$('div#tabs input[type="text"],
            select option:selected,
            input:checked,
            textarea').addClass('takethis');
```

Is grabbing *all* text fields, the selected option of *all* selects, *all* checked fields, and *all* textareas and adding the class `takethis` to it. Is that what you want to do?

**EDIT** I see what you're trying to do. If that is the case, why not just do this?

```
var table = $('<table>');
$('div#tabs :input').each(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val());
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    if(val) {
        var td1 = $('<td>').html(name);
        var td2 = $('<td>').html(val);
        $('<input>').attr({
            type: 'hidden',
            name: name
        }).appendTo(td2);
        $('<tr>').append(td1).append(td2).appendTo(table);
    }
});
$('#4tab').append(table);
```

Wouldn't this be simpler or am I missing a requirement here?

Comment: Well, I am  using the ui tabs and i want to fill out a from and automaticlly fill a fourth tab to just show the filled information. 

So if i want to select a different option how do I make sure the previous option is not in the select?
Here is the full code:
http://pastebin.com/m2c0f0847

Comment: This gives weird errors: 
[Exception... "'type property can't be changed' when calling method: [nsIDOMEventListener::handleEvent]" nsresult: "0x8057001e (NS_ERROR_XPC_JS_THREW_STRING)" location: "<unknown>" data: no]

Answer (score 2):

You need to call [`removeClass`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/removeClass) on the previously selected item.

Comment: What heartbreak. Beat by 30 seconds. :(

Comment: how would i know the previouse selected item?

Comment: Please see Paolo's answer - that is the best way to do it.

Comment: look @ my comment on paolo's answer. There is more info.