# remove class from radiobutton

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, radio-button

Houw would i do the same thing like this for radio buttons in jquery?

```
$("select option:not(:selected)").removeClass("takethis");
```

Comment: I already answered to this in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662373/remove-a-class-select-option-is-not-selected/662443, for radios as well inside the pseudo-accepted answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("input:radio, input:checkbox").not(":checked").removeClass('takethis');
```

Comment: One note, the jQuery docs recommend using "input:radio" and "input:checkbox" instead of ":radio" or ":checkbox" for efficiency.